# Not getting sorted arraylist of double values in ascending

Tags: java, database, sorting

I am not getting ordered list i.e. in ascending order of double values below is the code that I have tried all ways that I know but still I am not getting the desired result.

```
    locationB.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(SHOP.get(itemModall.getParent_id()).getLocationlat()));
    locationB.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(SHOP.get(itemModall.getParent_id()).getLocationlog()));
    listSort.add(new CUSTOM(MODALITEM.get(y).getParent_id(),distance));
    Collections.sort(listSort, CUSTOM::compareTo); //Sorting here
                   for (CUSTOM ss : listSort) {
                        Log.e("SSd", ss.getDistance() + "");
                    }




**This is my sorter class**


     class CUSTOM implements Comparable<CUSTOM> {

        String id;
        double distance;

        public CUSTOM(String id, double distance) {
            this.id = id;
            this.distance = distance;

        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public double getDistance() {
            return distance;
        }

        @Override

        public int compareTo(CUSTOM candidate) {

            return (this.getDistance() < candidate.getDistance() ? -1 :

                    (this.getDistance() == candidate.getDistance() ? 0 : 1));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  A minor note from me, consider " I have approached every method" not a helpful part of a title.

Answer (score 0):

Your class implements `Comparable`. You can simple call `Collections.sort(listSort)`. No need of the 2nd argument. Collections has 2 sort methods, one takes the list of Comparable objects and another one that takes list of objects and an instance of comparator.

1. `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)`
2. `public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`

For more information on comparable and comparator follow this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/)

Comment: will you please elaborate